# Parse.com to Heroku: use background job with heroku and scheduler

Tags: ios, node.js, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I would like to use the first function `sayHello` in my `jobs.js` in `parse-server-example`.

In my jobs.js I have this:

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');
Parse.initialize('xx', 'xx','xx');
Parse.serverURL = 'xx';
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

function sayHello() {
console.log('Hello');
}
```

I tried to run it with this terminal line command:

```
heroku run sayHello -a myAppName
```

returns:

```
Running sayHello on myAppName... up, run.6148
bash: sayHello: command not found
```

Comment: this is "nodeJS" question..

Comment: @typedef sorry, I didn't know, I would like to use it for iOS app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the job you want to run in its own file (without a .js extension) outside of a function.

```
    var Parse = require('parse/node');
    Parse.initialize('xx', 'xx','xx');
    Parse.serverURL = 'xx';
    console.log('Hello');
```

You can then run the following from the command line.

```
    heroku run node nameOfFile --app yourAppName
```

Comment: I think you can help me to solve my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338611/parse-com-use-background-job-with-heroku-and-scheduler-to-delete-pfobject

Thank you so much guy !

Comment: Or do you know how to use heroku run node file --app appName with Heroku Scheduler ?